# How to get remote branch information in git

Tags: git, github, repository, git-branch, ls-remote

We have git ls-remote --heads  command to list the branches created in the remote repository

Is there any way to get the branch information (like branch created date, author)

ex: I wish the output to be,

Branch-1   12/02/2013    user-1

your valuable thoughts please..

Comment: Git itself doesn't record when a branch was created, or who created it.

Comment: This could be helpful http://who-t.blogspot.rs/2012/06/git-branch-info.html